# Paradox (ObjectPal) Application causing General Protection Violations sporadically, looking for the Reason

Tags: debugging, crash, paradox

we have a pretty big application based on paradox / objectpal. since we moved the database from filebased tables (paradox) to ms sql 2008 express edition, we encounter lots of general protection violations (GPV) which appear sporadically. these errors seem to occur only with the paradox runtime, not with the developement edition, making debugging impossible. we did a lot to minimize those GPVs and it looks like its getting better. anyway, here and there are still annoying GPVs that crash the whole application.
so, what i´m looking for is kind of a debugger / logger for windows, to see what operations / methods cause these errors. like the windows event log, but with more details that could give a hint what and where to look for. i´m not sure if such a tool even exists... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two things you might try.

(1) Check with these guys

http://pnews.thedbcommunity.com/cgi-bin/dnewsweb.exe

on the subject of GPV (GPF) with the runtime but not with the development platform.  I'm sure the your question has come up there already.

Try searching the newsgroups first, but if that fails, your question probably belongs under "pnews.paradox-development".

(2) Add logging code to the application itself.  Add a library object to encapsulate an event log file, with a custom method to report an event.

Begin with a call from the open() and close() events of each design object (form, script, report, etc).  Then add a call to the action() method of any suspicious objects to detect and log specific actions.

This is tedious, I know, because you have to add the library to the Var() and Open() methods of every design object in the application.  But if it is done correctly, the operation of your application becomes amazingly transparent.

Comment: thank you for your answer. a few weeks ago, i´ve posted my question in the newsgroup you linked. also, i´ve collected all information regarding gpv (which are a lot) and followed all the instructions step by step. my hope was to get some kind of "debugger" or loggingtool for windows, to see which operation or method causes these errors. lots of the gpvs occur when dealing with wordfiles (ole-objects). i will try your advice with the logging-library.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience after years of using Paradox that GPV's can be a filtering issue.  If a filter is set in the form interactively then trying to open the form using setGenFilter, a conflict could occur causing a GPV. Bertil Isbergs Paradox Bug List from years ago is a long list of Paradox errors, fixes or work arounds.